# Finding the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $(1+x^2-x^3)^8$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

The coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $(1+x^2-x^3)^8$. I tried to factor it into two binomials but it became way to long to solve by hand.

Comment: How can you write $10$ as a sum of $2$s and $3$s? There aren't too many ways

Comment: Answer: 476. :)

Comment: ^^ How did you found that out so quickly

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Bx%5E2%E2%88%92x%5E3)%5E8

Comment: If you do the expansion as a binomial of $(1+f(x))^{n}$ then look at the $f(x)^{k}$ terms and consider which of them contains an $x^{10}$ term; it's only the k=4 and k=5 cases. Before that $(x^{2}-x^{3})^{3}$ only goes to $x^{9}$ and $(x^{2}-x^{3})^{6})$ starts at $x^{12}$. Then just work out the two coefficients.

Comment: There must be some another way as this question is from a 30min test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, the coefficient of  $x^{n}$ is given by
$$[x^{n}](1+x^2(1-x))^8=[x^{n}]\sum_{k=0}^8\binom{8}{k}x^{2k}(1-x)^k
=(-1)^n\sum_{n/3\leq k\leq \min(n/2,8)}\binom{8}{k}\binom{k}{n-2k}.$$
For $n=10$ we get
$$\sum_{4\leq k\leq 5}\binom{8}{k}\binom{k}{10-2k}=\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{2}+\binom{8}{5}\binom{5}{0}=476.$$

Answer (score 4):

$10=2\cdot 5$ or $2\cdot 3+2\cdot 2$. Hence
$$
\binom{8}{5}+\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}=476.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The pertinent part of the polynomial expansion *can* be done by hand without too much fuss:

$$\begin{align}
(1+x^2-x^3)^8&=(1+x^2)^8-8x^3(1+x^2)^7+{8\choose2}x^6(1+x^2)^6-{8\choose3}x^9(1+x^2)^5+\cdots\\
&=(1+x^2)^5((1+x^2)^3-8x^3(1+x^2)^2+28x^6(1+x^2)-56x^9)+\cdots\\
&=(1+x^2)^5((1+3x^2+3x^4+x^6)-8x^3(1+2x^2+x^4)+28x^6(1+x^2)-56x^9)+\cdots\\
&=(1+5x^2+10x^4+10x^6+5x^8+x^{10})(1+3x^2-8x^3+3x^4-16x^5+29x^6-8x^7+28x^8-56x^9)+\cdots\\
&=\cdots+(5\cdot28+10\cdot29+10\cdot3+5\cdot3+1\cdot1)x^{10}+\cdots\\
&=\cdots+(140+290+30+15+1)x^{10}+\cdots\\
&=\cdots+476x^{10}+\cdots
\end{align}$$